# How could I change the element width on server side by client device width

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to show desktop device with the width of `960px`

```
= line_chart chart_data, { 'width': "960px"}
```

and provide mobile device with width of `320ox`

```
= line_chart chart_data, { 'width': "320px"}
```

But I have no idea how to do it in server side, (view helper)

I use this gem https://github.com/airblade/chartjs-ror in my projecy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do things like that on the client side, but if you insist to do it on the server side, you can use a gem 'useragent', and then do:

```
  = line_chart chart_data, { 'width' => (user_agent.mobile? ? '320px' : '960px') }
```

Comment: i knew, it has better performance on client side, but my javascript is poor haha